# Stacked boxes in beamer (or more generally LaTeX)

Tags: beamer

I downloaded a pdf produced with the `beamer` class and I found these slides:

[image: First slide]
[image: Second slide]

I was wondering what command/environment/package was used to create the stacked rounded boxes. I searched the `beamer` manual but I found the `beamerboxesrounded` environment, which doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following based on `tcolorbox` and `tikz` might serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{nested tcolorboxes}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=6cm] 
some contents in the larger surrounding box

  \begin{tcolorbox}[hbox]
   smaller box
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{overlapping tcolorboxes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (lowest) 
      {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4cm] 
       some contents in the lowest box
       \end{tcolorbox}};
  \node[anchor=north west] (middle) at (lowest.east) [xshift=-1cm]  
      {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm] 
       some contents in the middle box
       \end{tcolorbox}};
  \node (upper) at (middle.south west) [yshift=-0.1cm] 
      {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm] 
      some contents in the upper box
      \end{tcolorbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does what I was looking for. However, the author is not an expert on LaTeX (let alone TikZ) so I suppose he used some other method.

Comment: If you know the author of the presentation well enough to assume their latex knowledge, why don't you just ask them how they created thiese slides?

Comment: He didn't answer. Besides, I prefer to get an expert opinion.